# How to select GIF file from Gallery?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android development. I am currently working in an app in which I have to pick GIF file from the Gallery. I am using this below code

```
image_gif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/gif");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_GIF_REQUEST);
```

But by using this above code, my Gallery shows all type of files(.jpeg, .png, .mp4 etc.). And whenever I select one of them files, my app will be crashed and gives badTokenException. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: chech this link https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/how-to-view-animated-gifs-in-android

Answer (score -1):

List all the gif's in your sdcard with code below, and then let user pic particular gif from list.

```
private List<String> getListOfFiles(String path) {

    File files = new File(path);

    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {

        private final List<String> exts = Arrays.asList("gif");

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            String ext;
            String path = pathname.getPath();
            ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            return exts.contains(ext);
        }
    };

    final File [] filesFound = files.listFiles(filter);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (filesFound != null && filesFound.length > 0) {
        for (File file : filesFound) {
           list.add(file.getName());
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I didn't get when to call this method and what do you mean by String path.

Comment: On button click, where you are opening gallery to pic gif file, simply show a list of all gifs from your sdcard and then select one.

Like one we can reference whatsapp media sharing, clicking on gallery we get list of images, videos and gifs.

String path here is Absolute file path.